# Scheme - list functions with filter

Tags: string, list, dictionary, filter, scheme

I am currently working on a homework assignment with MIT scheme, and have come across a few problems that are supposedly very short, though I'm a bit confused as to how to implement some of them.

One problem asks me to write a function that returns a list with all the integers removed. I did manage to solve that,

```
(define (f2a lst) (map (lambda(x) (remove number? x)) lst))
```

though I'm confused as to how I can rewrite it to not use remove, but rather use a filter.
*note: `(f2a '(("a" 1 "b") (2 "c") (-1 "d") (-2)))` returns `'(("a" "b") ("c") ("d"))`

The other two problems are ones to which I haven't found any solutions.

They ask me to write a function that returns a list with all positive odd and negative even integers removed. For example,

```
(f2b '(("a" 1 "b") (2 "c") (-1 "d") (-2)))
```

returns

```
(("a" "b") (2 "c") (-1 "d"))
```

I have some code down that is incorrect, but I feel shows how I have tried to approach solving this one:

```
(define (f2b lst)
  (lambda(x) 
    (cond ((and (positive? x) (odd? x)) (filter x lst))
      ((and (negative? x) (even? x)) (filter x lst))
      (else "this should never print"))))
```

The last problem simply asks for a function that returns a string consisting of all strings appended together in a list. `(f2c '(("a" 1 "b") (2 "c") (-1 "d") (-2)))` returns "abcd".

I almost managed to figure this one out, but got stuck when it kept returning strange values. This is the code I have:

```
(define (f2c lst)
  (lambda(x)
    (map (lambda (x) (filter string? x)) lst)
    (list x))
  (string-append (car lst) (cdr lst)))
```

In terms of higher-order syntax, I'm limited to map, filter, accumulate and sum. I am not asking for a direct answer, but rather some help for me to figure out what I need to do. What am I doing wrong with my code? Any assistance given with this is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Filtering-Lists.html#Filtering-Lists) for `remove` says, "Like filter, except that the returned list contains only those elements not satisfying predicate." So, to use `filter` instead of `remove`, just negate your predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the input and the desired output is identical in the first two problems; the only thing that differs is the predicate on when/when-not to remove an element.  For the second case it would be:

```
(define (f2b lst) 
  (map (lambda (sublst)
        (remove (lambda (x)
                  (and (number? x)
                       (or (and (positive? x) (odd?  x))
                           (and (negative? x) (even? x)))))
                 sublst))
       lst))
```

Since only the predicate differs you can generalize this as:

```
  (define (f2x predicate)
    (lambda (lst)
      (map (lambda (sublst) (remove predicate sublst)) lst)))
  (define f2a (f2x number?))
  (define f2b (f2x (lambda (x) 
                     (and (number? x)
                          (or (and (positive? x) (odd?  x))
                              (and (negative? x) (even? x))))))
```

For your last problem, you can use the result of the first problem as:

```
(define (f2c lst)
  (apply string-append (apply append (f2a list))))
```

Also, note that your syntax for f2b and f2a is incorrect.  You are using

```
(define (func arg) 
  (lambda (x) ...))
```

which means that `(func arg)` returns a function which isn't what you want.

Comment: Thank you for explaining things, though there are two things I'm noticing that are off: for the f2b code, it doesn't entirely seem to work, since when running it, it checks a string for an integer value and returns an error (i.e. object "pie", passed as first argument to integer-negative?, is not correct type)
. Also, for the code you posted on f2c list, I can't comment on whether or not that is right since at the point I am currently at in the course I am taking, we haven't gotten far enough to use code like that.

Comment: I've added number? to the predicate.